# understanding revealing modular pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

hey guys i am just trying to understand the **REVEALING MODULAR PATTERN**, i see the following simple depiction of the revealing modular pattern:

```
var myRevealingModule = (function () {

        var privateCounter = 0;

        function privateFunction() {
            privateCounter++;
        }

        function publicFunction() {
            publicIncrement();
        }

        function publicIncrement() {
            privateFunction();
        }

        function publicGetCount(){
          return privateCounter;
        }

        // Reveal public pointers to
        // private functions and properties

       return {
            start: publicFunction,
            increment: publicIncrement,
            count: publicGetCount
        };

    })();

myRevealingModule.start();
```

now the following disadvantages are stated of the revealing moduar pattern ::

> A disadvantage of this pattern is that if a private function refers to
>   a public function, that public function can't be overridden if a patch
>   is necessary. This is because the private function will continue to
>   refer to the private implementation and the pattern doesn't apply to
>   public members, only to functions.

i don't quite understand what the above para means , can somebody explain ? private function refers to the public function , did't quite get that , can somebody break it down ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```js
Mod = function() {
  
  
  function inc() {
    return value() + 1;
  }
  
  var value = function() { return 42 }
  
  var valuePlusOne = function() { return inc() }
  
  return {
    value: value,
    valuePlusOne: valuePlusOne
  }
}()

document.write(Mod.valuePlusOne()) // 43

Mod.value = function() {
  return 999
}

document.write(Mod.valuePlusOne()) // still 43, not 1000
```

The problem is that `inc` uses `var value` from its containing scope, not the `value` property of the module object. When you change the module, this doesn't affect `var value` from the scope.

A workaround is to bind private functions to the object being returned:

```js
Mod = function() {
  
  var value = function() { return 42 }
  
  var valuePlusOne = function() { return inc() }
  
  var me = {
    value: value,
    valuePlusOne: valuePlusOne
  }
  
  function inc() {
    return me.value() + 1;
  }
  
 
  return me;
}()

document.write(Mod.valuePlusOne()) // 43

Mod.value = function() {
  return 999
}

document.write(Mod.valuePlusOne()) // 1000
```

Comment: @george refering to your 1st example why does `value()` inside `inc()` still refer to the old `value()` even though the `value()` function has been overriden  .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik: added an explanation.